# Please don't abuse of the custom close reasons (nor just agree with the previous close voters)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've seen this for a while now. We are (miss)using the custom close reason:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone spoted the problem here? As you can see, both say the same with different wording. Why should we close it with a custom reason instead of the already loaded ones?

Same happens with Android questions (that has nothing to do with Ubuntu). The first close reason is **"This is not about Ubuntu."**. This should cover all cases where the question *is not about Ubuntu*, I don't consider that we should write a close reason *just for* Android, if we get several of these questions we could add the correct place were to ask to the first close reason. Of course, I'm not saying that you shouldn't write your own custom reason, but only write it **if the other close reasons doesn't fit**. If there is already a close reason that applies, why write another?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I agree and would be tempted to expand the plea to:

## Look at what you're doing when you're reviewing things!

We've seen a few dodgy closes and attempted-closes slip through since the review system came in. It's a shame that closes can't be countered like-for-like.

By running through the reviews and rushing things by just agreeing, you're hurting the site. Don't do it.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, we are most of the time "agreeing" with the previous voters.