# Add filter to see all duplicates

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a way to filter for only questions labeled as duplicate which are linked to an answer?

For example:

- [Duplicate sources.list entry but cannot find the duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156227/duplicate-sources-list-entry-but-cannot-find-the-duplicates)

Being linked to:

- [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

Is there a way to see every question link the best answer? This might be useful when trying to cull the excess duplicate posts, by allowing people to flag for removal. Or other similar purposes.

Comment: Why not flagging the crappy duplicates for deletion?

Comment: @Braiam I thought I was supposed to make the duplicates as high of quality (if possible) as the questions they were pointing to, if not is there still a way to go through/see what are being pointed to as duplicates?

Comment: ["Having dozens and dozens of variations of the same question is clearly bad."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) It doesn't really help that there are 500 duplicates of the same question, in fact if there are 500 duplicates of the same question we should critically check why in the world they are getting produced. BTW, [related](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7982/169736)

Comment: @Braiam I am going to edit this question. I completely agree with what your last comment says, and it makes sense, but I still do see a purpose for this possible feature (I will put in question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called "Linked" which should show all the linked questions, the problem is that it shows too those questions that somewhere in the post or comments has a link to a post... so, there are super-referenced questions that you get lots of non-duplicates. The only solution is using a query:

http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/198064/find-duplicate-of-a-specific-post?ID=120621

This query will find all post that links to [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry) and any other ID you like. I presume you know how to find the ID, but just in case `https://askubuntu.com/questions/<ID-IS-HERE>/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry`.

The query is thanks to animuson's [Find duplicates of deleted posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/169338/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts) which share lots of stuff.

Comment: That's good enough for me.