# How can I search my old (previous) answers?

Tags: support, searching

I sometimes see questions that I know are duplicates because I've answered another question that asked the same thing. Unfortunately, I don't know the name of the exact question I answered before so that I can mark a duplicate.

Is there a way to use the search to search for keywords only in my answers?

Comment: This answer by Braiam http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9218/add-filter-to-see-all-duplicates?answertab=active#tab-top has something that you might like looking at too. (Somewhat related to searching)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use search using the following:

```
<keyword> user:me is:a
```

This will search for answers (`is:a` = is an answer) by you that contain the word `<keyword>`. If you want to search for all posts by you (answers and questions), just remove the `is:a` part.

Here's an example of looking for the word `local` in posts by me:

[image]

You can pretty much use this for everything else in the search. For instance, you can use it to search for questions of a specific tag by you using `[tag] user:me`. This will display all questions/answers by you on questions that were tagged with `tag`.

Comment: that search all posts not only answers.

Comment: Add `is:a` to filter for just answers.

Comment: Or you can use `is:q` to filter for just questions. Thank you I also was looking for this commands. thanks