# The audit review system - dubious posts

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

This is the second time I got that *unloved*  "Stop! Look and Listen" for a question I voted to close after reading it several times and trying to understand it.

[image: review audit fail]

The question really is not clear to me: it seems he is asking for a shortcut like <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> that switches between windows of the same application, but then he states *Oscar goes to tmux* - which left me only with several *???*.

<sub>My first version for the post used much stronger language :-)</sub>

---

After having read several comments I want to point out that I didn't want to discuss if this question should be closed or not - my purpose was to show that it is entirely possible for one question to be regarded as *good* by some reviewers and as *bad* by others - all acting in good faith - so those audits (in the close queue) eventually **will** go wrong.

Comment: I normally go outside the queue and vote them to close... is because we have this kinds of doggy posts the review audits will not be so effective.

Comment: @Braiam I understand your motivation - but this **cannot** be the purpose of the audits, can it?

Comment: The same happened to me with this off-topic question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422135/how-to-get-the-url-from-a-file-using-a-shell-script -- I'm wondering: how does the audit system work? Audits aren't much useful this way.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini That question is not off-topic. Maybe you got a wrong link?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179651/close-vote-review-audit-flawed-fails-without-casting-vote I currently have a bounty on it using most my MSO rep.

Comment: @Mateo not quite - I **did want** to close that question - and I still would VTC.

Comment: wonder if they throw it out of the review audit system if it get's edited - if not that may prevent this kind of close reason being a review audit question.

Comment: Had I got a post like that I would rather edit it, never flag to close.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa we are not talking about flags here but about votes.

Comment: Ok, could you then explain what a vote is in this context?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa see http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Weird... it got no votes...

Comment: I mean, close votes...

Comment: @Seth yeah, that was the one http://askubuntu.com/review/close/229144

Comment: @Braiam that double link edit is a nice trick :-)

Answer (score 5):

No, actually the lack of a well defined **quality** policies will dismiss the usefulness of the audits, I've failed 2 audits already just because of this (and went outside of the queue and voted to close them). The system selects seriously upvoted posts as examples, but upvotes is not the face value of a post (for example this [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)).

Your judgment was right, that Q is very subjective:

> So many answers and yet the (*subjectively*) most valuable suggestion for me is delivered in a comment ... so ironic.

This is a change of behavior in how to use the terminal and the window manager. For example, I normally don't have 2 window of the same application opened at the same time, meaning: 1 Iceweasel, 1 terminal, 1 Chromium, 1 zim wiki, 1 window of whatever, and then organize them by tabs. For **me** that's efficient since I don't use several terminal window.

> How to handle multiple terminals (and instances of same application in general) efficiently using the keyboard?

^ This is precisely what I don't do... why I would need several window of the same terminal when I could get just 1 and several tabs?

Comment: agreed. votes are no indication of quality and on-topicness. It would be preferable if the test cases were chosen manually.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said earlier, the audit system is not smart. All it can do is take posts it sees as "good" (ones with lots of upvotes, both on the question and answer(s)). I'm not sure what all the system looks at, it probably looks at views too.

But, in essence, the audit system relies on *us* to define what a good question is and what a bad question is. This is why I disagree with the current implementation of close vote audits, they're just too relative.

AFAIK the audit system doesn't give out auto review bans, so I wouldn't worry about audits so much in the close vote queue. I'm actually hoping to get them pulled from that queue.

---

Now, here is my opinion about that question.

I understand it perfectly, the OP usually has many terminals up each running a different program and he doesn't like the "window spread" effect when he tries to switch between them, because it's hard to tell them apart.

I would have suggested the same thing, a terminal multiplexer.

Comment: I appreciate that the question is clear for you - what I contend is  the connotation (of the audit text) "you didn't look carefully", the idea behind voting is that a person can make errors, but honestly not careless.

Comment: Have a look at @braiam's comment on my question - taking every review out of the queue cannot be the purpose of audits either. The way audits are currently working is disrupting and counter productive.

Comment: @guntbert I agree with most of what you say, we aren't SO and I don't think we need to worry about bad reviewers in the close vote queue.

Comment: Uh? [yes](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7561/169736), [we](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8421/reviewers-need-to-be-mindful-of-their-actions?cb=1) do

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I misspoke, we *do* need to worry about them, but I don't think these audits are the answer in the close queue. They work fine in the other queues, but they don't work well here.

Comment: Well, those are claims *only* related to the close queue, through.

Comment: @Braiam That's *what I said*!

Comment: "I don't think these audits are the answer in the close queue" I think *we need audits in the close queues.* Dunno where's the problem.

Comment: @Braiam Not the way they are currently implemented, no.

Comment: Well, the system was designed to get the *high quality* questions to test us.

Comment: @Braiam I don't see where it has failed in that endeavor. We all have slightly different opinions, the system can't make us all happy, but overall when it comes to what questions it chooses, it seems ok. What are you getting at? You seem to be going random on me.