# Broken review test

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

Moments ago a late answer popped up in the review queue with a link to a bash script debugger hosted at SourceForge. I started by editing the answer (which was not well formatted), but whenever I clicked the *edit* button I would get a message like:

> This answer is deleted [sic].

Thinking that the user had deleted the answer, I proceeded to the following answer in the queue. But I got this message instead:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. This answer was of very poor quality, and needed
>   significant improvements to be useful – passing over such posts hurts
>   the ability of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to
>   fix such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very
>   low quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.;

This test is obviously broken, if it is informing the answer has been deleted, no one will follow links or flag it.

Comment: I got the same message again on another post: "This post is deleted and cannot be edited." This time I simply left the review queue to avoid the "STOP! Look and Listen." greet.

Comment: Btw, I don't think you should worry about getting that message, it won't deny you access to the review queues if you get it multiple times. From what I know, it is just a test.

Comment: @Dan, being annoyed is not the same as being worried - as reviewers we (try to) do a service to the site.

Comment: What was the review?

Comment: This happened in the Late Answers review queue.

Comment: @Dan Some people may perceive the message as aggressive, and would do anything to avoid being shouted upon (e.g. avoid reviewing altogether). Especially when it happens for no good reason: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8597/the-audit-review-system-dubious-posts .

Comment: I just got another *Late Answer* with this problem. If this is being caused by audits then I would strongly suggest a revision of the process. So far this does not seem to happen with *First Post* reviews.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Looking back at the review history, if you're talking about [this post](http://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/230672) it post certainly wasn't a good post and was something you should have flagged/downvoted.

Comment: No, this bug is present in every single test. If your first action on every review is to click *edit* you will get the "This post is deleted" message on each and every test.

Comment: If this is a "bug" then tag it as such. You are using the discussion tag and we don't know what are you trying to "discuss"

Comment: @LuísdeSousa That isn't a bug.. can you clarify why you think it is?

Comment: Is it supposed to function this way? What is the purpose?

Comment: Read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/213575

Comment: @LuísdeSousa After reading Shog9's answer below I now understand what you are getting at. However, you shouldn't have edited that post.

Answer (score 2):

This has been [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193830/why-doesnt-attempting-to-edit-count-as-a-pass-for-a-review-audit) several [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169989/this-post-was-deleted-and-cannot-be-edited-on-audit) before. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce it reliably.

...With *one* exception: [Opening the post editor in a new tab does not pass a review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217781/opening-the-post-editor-in-a-new-tab-does-not-pass-a-review-audit)

If you trigger the edit link on a review item, it will normally let you pass the audit and move on to the next item. *However*, this is activated via JavaScript - if you open the URL associated with the edit link (for instance, in a new browser tab or window) it will try to just give you the normal editor - and if the post is deleted and you have < 10K reputation, this will fail with the error you observed.

If you can figure out how to reproduce this *without* opening the editor in a new tab/window, please share what you learned.

Comment: Whenever I click the *edit* button on a review test I get the message above. I am now able to avoid all review tests by clicking *edit* on each review. There is [more discussion about it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8685/stop-look-and-listen).

Comment: What browser, @LuísdeSousa?