# My last rant on review audits

Tags: discussion, support, review, review-audits

Please bear with me - this is definitely the last rant from me about the review queue.

Because it told me again:

[image: screenshot]

That's what I will do - I'll **stop** using the review queue, instead I will **look** at posts just as I browse them and I will **listen** to some nice music :-)

In earnest: I am told that a post (https://askubuntu.com/review/close/231355) about *mint* (see 2nd comment) is not OT - grrrr.

Comment: **Why that thing has 6 UPVOTES?**

Comment: Probably because its a good question - he only said "mint" later.

Comment: Come on guys, the theme should be enough to make you suspicious...

Comment: Yeah that's a bummer - power through it though, despite the problems IMO I think having these tests helps us more than hurts us, despite the occasional frustration!

Comment: Although I would flag that particular question - "I'm using Linux Mint as my O/S." - I agree that the audits are becoming more than just a nuisance when compounded with [the buggy tests popping up](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8622/broken-review-test). I have also reduced my presence at the review queue.

Comment: @Braiam - 7 upvotes - for once nothing do with me. I agree with Luis de Sousa - also, I think quite a lot of the flipping things are useless and annoying, and it would be nice if the amount could be reduced slightly *(i.e. A LOT)*.

Comment: @Wilf As the one that push the review audits I've seen users to do horrific things. Now the audits is showing that the problem is more profound and critical. I know audits can become a nuance, I've failed 2 in the close queue, but those that I've failed I voted to close them too when failed the audit.