# Reviewer Consequences

Tags: discussion, review

Do reviewers suffer consequences if they exercise poor judgement in their task of reviewing posts?

I refer particularly to 'robot' style reviews where the reviewer appears to give little care to the task in hand and manages, as an example, to review 20 posts in almost as many seconds - presumably in their quest for badge awards or for some other odd purpose.

In another thread just over a year ago

> [The audit review system - dubious posts](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8597/the-audit-review-system-dubious-posts)

Seth said "AFAIK the audit system doesn't give out auto review bans, so I wouldn't worry about audits so much"

Is this still the position? Do reviewers suffer no consequences for robot style reviewing?

Comment: The audit system does do bans. You can get banned from failing audits for 2 days at least. I have, after failing one too many audits.

Comment: but how many is too many?

Comment: I don't think there's one number - it's a combination of both failed audits and the time spent on reviewing. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177073/cant-do-reviews-after-failing-1-audit

Comment: Most reassuring, thanks for the link @muru.

Comment: Then there are audits that fail you when it shouldn't